# About Xauth and DISPLAY variable

Tags: x11, display, xauth

I'd like to understand about `xauth` and `DISPLAY` variable and how `ssh -X` auto-generate the `DISPLAY` variable and why it choose those values? I've seen is somewhere that is not correct to set `DISPLAY` manually as well.

what mean each column of this output?

```
[root@serverdg ~]# xauth list
serverdg2/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  87b515cf92e356b7702d3afd721f7fe1
serverdg2/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  e8f9bfb5abac8757f4864656ce4f9bd1
serverdg/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7270008abd9f949a9b1af76c7742da9e
serverdg/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  bb2f1768b445f372e5975d728579517e
serverdg/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  475b9a6cbc7567b956511d5d2d27950b
```

Why `ssh -X` generate a value for `DISPLAY` variable with `10.0` like in this example?

```
[root@serverdg ~]# echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

Everything I know is that I need to copy those values of `xauth list` and `DISPLAY` if I change my current user user to another user (`su - user`) to be able to use the X because this values are generate when is made a new login with `ssh`.

Comment: What is your exact question? "Why is it `localhost:10.0` and not `localhost:1.0`?" A: to leave space for 10 local X11 servers (0..9), assuming they still want to listen on a tcp socket (which they don't anymore do by default).

Answer (score 3):

The `DISPLAY` environment variable tells an application how to connect the [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server. The X server is the part of the system that displays windows on the screen. A display is something on which windows can be displayed.

A unix system can have multiple displays, for example on multiple [virtual consoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console), or on [multiple real consoles](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg_multiseat), or because some displays are [virtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), or because some displays are accessed over the network. `ssh -X` forwards a connection to a remote display over the network.

Each display has a number. The purpose of these numbers is just to tell the displays apart. `:0` is display number 0, `:1` is display number 1, etc. One of the ways the display number is used is in how it allows applications to connect to the X server: it is used to calculate the name of a [socket file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) (`/etc/.X11-unix/X0`, …) or the number of a TCP port (6000 plus the display number) on which the X server listens.

The `.0` part after the display number is an obsolete concept. It's a “screen” number, where a display can consist of multiple screens, and a window is tied to a particular screen. On modern systems, the X server presents a single screen and allows application windows to move between monitors. `:NUMBER` is equivalent to `:NUMBER.0`.

There can be a machine name before the colon. This allows TCP communication between the application and the X server. This communication is not protected against network snooping and man-in-the-middle, so it's mostly deprecated on real networks, but can be useful in some cases, for example on a network between virtual machines running on the same host. In practice, if both work,`localhost:NUMBER` is functionally equivalent to `:NUMBER` (but `:NUMBER` may use a faster communication mechanism under the hood, and it's possible for only one of them to work because not all X servers listen both locally and via TCP; it's even technically possible to have different servers listening on `localhost:NUMBER` and `:NUMBER` but that would be a misconfiguration somewhere).

The entity that creates an X display must choose a display number. (It might do that by letting the server decide, but if so it needs to find out what number the server picked in order to set `DISPLAY` for applications.) Most programs pick the lowest available number, or a number that's hard-coded in some configuration file. In order to leave room for physical displays, SSH only picks numbers starting at 10.

It's generally not correct to set `DISPLAY` manually because only the entity that creates the display can pick the number. For example, in the case of `ssh -X`, that's SSH itself. If you set `DISPLAY` manually, you might get the number wrong, or you might advertise a display that doesn't exist (for example if X11 forwarding was refused).

Other users, or users on other machines, could attempt to connect to an X display that isn't their own. Because X was designed to allow remote connection, it couldn't just rely on the unix user. So X has an [authorization mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization): when an application wants to connect to an X display, it must prove that it is authorized. In the modern world, there's just one authorization mechanism, which is a “cookie” in the `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1` format (16 bytes, presented in hexadecimal). The cookie is a long random string that is generated when the server starts and stored in a file that only the legitimate user can read. In order to connect to the X display, the application must send the cookie value to the server. If the cookie value is incorrect, the server rejects the connection.

Comment: "The .0 part ... a “screen” number, ..., and an application is tied to a particular screen." An application is/was in no way *tied* to a particular screen on such a setup. As I already [tried](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611742/414777) (apparently in vain) to explain.

Comment: @user414777 Well, yes, but only if there's a way to move the application to another screen. What application or window manager in current use allows that?

Comment: "`localhost:NUMBER` is functionally equivalent to `:NUMBER`" That's not true. The display number only has meaning within a protocol (tcp or unix). You can quite easily verify it by starting a `Xephyr :10` server, and then running `ssh -X localhost`. `DISPLAY=localhost:10 xclock` will show a clock on your main screen, and `DISPLAY=:10 xclock` within the Xephyr server.

Comment: The window manager cannot do that, but an application can seemlessly recreate a window on another screen. (I think that emacs was able to that). But that's beside that point; an application or wm may also not let you reparent a window to another window *within the same screen*, or change its background color from yellow to green, that doesn't mean that it's "tied to yellow" ;-)

Comment: @user414777 And an application can open windows on multiple displays. But that doesn't mean that the value of `DISPLAY` is unimportant.

Comment: And unfortunately, on many "modern" distros, the X11 server will only check the user of the client connected over X11 sockets (via getsockopt(SO_PEERCRED), and **no longer care about any cookie or authentication whatsoever**. But I have annoyed you enough for today, I will not pour over the rest of the answer.